# Wrong model prediction

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, classification, binary-data

I have a binary classification problem. I want to detect raindrops on the image. I trained a simple model, but my prediction is not good. I want to have a prediction between 0 and 1.

For my first try, i used relu for all layers accept the final(I used softmax). As the optimizer, i used binary_crossentropy and i changed it into the categorical_crossentropy. Both of them didn't work.

```
opt = Adam(lr=LEARNING_RATE, decay=LEARNING_RATE / EPOCHS)

cnNetwork.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=lr),
              metrics=['accuracy']) 


inputShape = (height, width, depth)

    # if we are using "channels first", update the input shape
    if K.image_data_format() == "channels_first":
        inputShape = (depth, height, width)

    # First layer is a convolution with 20 functions and a kernel size of 5x5 (2 neighbor pixels on each side)
    model.add(Conv2D(20, (5, 5), padding="same",
        input_shape=inputShape))
    # our activation function is ReLU (Rectifier Linear Units)
    model.add(Activation("relu"))
    # second layer is maxpooling 2x2 that reduces our image resolution by half 
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

    # Third Layer - Convolution, twice the size of the first convoltion
    model.add(Conv2D(40, (5, 5), padding="same"))
    model.add(Activation("relu"))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

    # Fifth Layer is Full connected flattened layer that makes our 3D images into 1D arrays
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(500))
    model.add(Activation("relu"))

    # softmax classifier
    model.add(Dense(classes))
    model.add(Activation("softmax"))
```

I expect to get for ex .1 for the first class and .9 for the second. In the result, i get 1 , 1.3987518e-35. The main problem is that i always get 1 as a prediction.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using binary_crossentropy and there is nothing wrong in the output you have got. The output 1 , 1.3987518e-35 means the probability of first class is almost 1 and probability of second class is very close to 0 (1e-35).

Comment: but 1.3987518e-35 = −31.1977984

Comment: I'm not sure how you got -31. 1.3987518e-35 means 1 , 1.3987518 * 10^-35

Comment: https://www.graphpad.com/support/faq/what-does-it-mean-when-some-results-have-e-in-the-number/

Comment: How a neural net can be 100% sure that it is 1? Isn't it impossible?

Comment: @KyrKalash There are many reasons why your predictions are very close to 1. One reason is you could be overfitting on a small dataset